# How I can change Vega schema dynamically

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have following code in Vega lite. I want to change transform filter 1850 to 2000. Please suggest how I can Change transform filter of schema. If possible  is there any sample example for dynamic data change and update view. 
Data for population took from
https://vega.github.io/editor/data/population.json

```js
var yourVlSpec = {
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
    "data": {
        "url": "https://vega.github.io/editor/data/population.json",
        "format": {
            "type": "json"
        }
    },
    "transform": [
      {
          "filter": "datum.year == 1850"
      }
    ],
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
        "x": {
            "aggregate": "sum",
            "field": "people",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "axis": {
                "title": "population"
            }
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "scale": {
            "rangeStep": 21
        }
    }
}

vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec).then(function (result) {
    result.spec.transform[0] = '{filter: "datum.year == 2000"}';

}).catch(console.error);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Embedding Vega-Lite</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@3.0.10"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@2.1.2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@3.0.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vis"></div>
    <div id="view"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with selections (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html) and a filter based on that selection (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/filter.html#selection-predicate). If that's not an option, you will need to use Vega Signals and the Vega View API.